# postgresql groupby count where date is between

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count

So I have a table where I want the count of rows where the customer is McDonalds's and Date > 2019-06-30

I am trying

```
select "Customer",
    Count("Customer")
FROM 
   public.master_environmental_data
WHERE "Customer" = 'McDonald''s' AND "Date" > '2021-06-30';
```

However I am getting this error:

```
column "master_environmental_data.Customer" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select "Customer",
               ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8
```

What is the correct query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should add a `GROUP BY` at the end of the query:

```
select "Customer",
    Count("Customer")
FROM 
   public.master_environmental_data
WHERE "Customer" = 'McDonald''s' AND "Date" > '2021-06-30'
GROUP BY "Customer";
```